# Return in js recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, return

Can you please explain me why is this code returning

> 'xxxcba'

while I only have the `return 'xxx';` command?

```js
function reverseString(str) {
  if (str === '')
    return 'xxx';
  else
    return reverseString(str.substr(1)) + str.charAt(0);
}

console.log(reverseString('abc'));
```

Comment: Cause you build up a stack that is resolved after you hit your base condition. This means that for each function call you get your base return value plus the one that was added at the respective call. 

Just google recursion you will find many sites explaining the concept you didn't yet fully understand!

Comment: `I only have the return 'xxx';` - no you don't ... you also have `return reverseString(str.substr(1)) + str.charAt(0);` - clearly you don't understand your own code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following:

```
reverseString("abc")
== reverseString("bc") + "a"
== reverseString("c") + "b" + "a"
== reverseString("") + "c" + "b" + "a"
== "xxx" + "c" + "b" + "a"
== "xxxcba"
```

Answer (score 0):

You will see the magic when you remove `xxx` from the return and replace with a `''` if you wanted to perform a reverse of a string in a recursive way. You are not handling the base case properly